# How do I select individual words inside a Google document using selenium webdriver (C# or Java)

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver, automated-tests

I'm currently testing content within google documents using selenium webdriver.  Some of my tests involve selecting individual words within a google document then performing some action against them such as bold the word or change the font type for the specific word etc.

I would simply like to be able to select a word like this:

http://s10.postimg.org/9x3d4f1q1/image.png

And here is the code returned from the Google document:

http://s24.postimg.org/e4zfocy9x/image.png

I have tried using send keys to send a ctrl+a command and this works for me but the problem is, I need to do a little house keeping prior to running my test by creating a document with one word inside it.  Kind of defeats the purpose of automating this.

I have tried using substring to get specific words but then I can't perform any action on the String as it will not be a web element.

Would someone be so kind and point me in the right direction?  Thanks very much for any help.  It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can only manipulate WebElement

In your example you won't be able to manipulate only "is" which is a text, not a HTML node.

The best you can do is selecting the `<span>`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'This is a paragraph')]"));
```

and do whatever you want with it

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back.  I'm able to find the xpath but then that just gets me the entire paragraph and unfortunately I need to be able to perform actions on individual words

Comment: Yes I know but unless each word is separated in your html like `<span>word</span>`, you won't be able to select each word separately

Comment: Would someone else like to offer some input please?